# play-framework 2.0, is it possible to add a GET variable through the reverse router?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In one of my methods of my controller, called `PageController`, I have

```
return redirect(routes.PageController.page_view("main", "home"));
```

This goes to `/main/home`. How can I add a GET variable to this, so that it should for example go to something like `/main/home?redirect=0`?

Comment: Please mark question if you got an answer or post your answer, to help other people in future

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same, if I understand your question:

```
public static Result GO_TO_OVERVIEW = redirect(routes.Bookmarks.index(0, "description", "asc", ""));
```

And my routes declaration for this looks like:

```
GET     /bookmarks  controllers.Bookmarks.index(p:Int ?= 0, s ?= "description", o ?= "asc", f ?= "")
```

And my index function:

```
public static Result index(int page, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
    if (sortBy.isEmpty() || sortBy == null) {
        page = 0;
        sortBy = "description";
        order = "asc";
    }
    User user = User.getLoggedInUser(session("user"));
    Page<models.Bookmark> orderList = models.Bookmark.page(page, 20, sortBy, order, filter, user);
    return ok(views.html.bookmarks.list.render(orderList, sortBy, order, filter));
}
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: Hi, yea I got it to work, I typed into my router `GET  /:namespace/:name    controllers.Application.page_view(namespace: String, name: String, redirect:Boolean ?= true)` which gives me the option to pass a boolean when I want, cheers